# add attribute to element after a angular-ui-bootstrap renders its template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-1.5

I would like to add a 'ng-click' to an element that ui-bootstrap renders from the accordion directive.

I am using angular 1.5, so there are a lot of solutions out there but they dont work for angular 1.5.

Comment: Can you post the related html and js codes?

Comment: Can you provide more information? You can create your own template for the accordion and put ng-click on the element. Would that help?

Comment: Can I create my own template without editing the ui-bootstrap source code

Comment: did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct you can override the template with your own template and put ng-click on the element in the template.

**template-url (Default: template/accordion/accordion.html) - Add the ability to     override the template used on the component.**

Comment: Can I do this without editing ui-bootstrap source code?

Comment: Yes, if you check the ui-bootstrap accordion docs it tells you how to specify a different template by using the template-url attribute. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.3.2/

Comment: Yes, you just have to provide your own template.no source code change